# How can I make Rails exclude application.erb when rendering the layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm making an AAJX request to an action in a controller. I fetch the rendered HTML and display it in a tag in the current page. The view that I'm POSTing to, renders the layout with the default application.erb. I would like rails to use the default layout for the controller/action but not render the main application.erb. How do I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can tell `render` not to use your application's layout using `render :layout => false`